# How to initialize an object that requires __new__ and __init__

Tags: python

I'm creating a class `sequence`, which inherits from the builtin `list` and will hold an ordered collection of a second class: `d0` which inherits from `int`. `d0`, in addition to its `int` value must contain a secondary value, `i` which denotes where it exists in the class and a reference to the class itself.

My understanding is because `int` is an immutable type, I have to use the `__new__` method, and because it will have other attributes, I need to use `__init__`.

I've been trying for a while to get this to work and I've explored a few options.

Attempt 1:

```
class sequence(list):
    def __init__(self, data):
        for i, elem in enumerate(data): self.append( d0(elem, i, self) )

class d0(int):
    def __new__(self, val, i, parent):
        self.i = i
        self.parent = parent
        return int.__new__(d0, val)

x = sequence([1,2,3])
print([val.i for val in x])
```

This was the most intuitive to me, but every time `self.i` is assigned, it overwrites the `i` attribute for all other instances of `d0` in `sequence`. Though I'm not entirely clear why this happens, I understand that `__new__` is not the place instantiate an object.

Attempt 2:

```
class sequence(list):
    def __init__(self, data):
        for i, val in enumerate(data): self.append( d0(val, i, self) )

class d0(int):
    def __new__(cls, *args):
        return super().__new__(cls, *args)

    def __init__(self, *args):
        self = args[0]
        self.i = args[1]
        self.parent = args[2]

x = sequence([1,2,3])
print([val.i for val in x])
```

This raises `TypeError: int() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)`, though I'm not sure why.

Attempt 3:

```
class sequence(list):
    def __init__(self, data):
        for i, val in enumerate(data):
            temp = d0.__new__(d0, val)
            temp.__init__(i, self)
            self.append(temp)

class d0(int):
    def __new__(cls, val):
        return int.__new__(d0, val)

    def __init__(self, i, parent):
        self.i = i
        self.parent = parent

x = sequence([1,2,3])
print([val.i for val in x])
```

This accomplishes the task, but is cumbersome and otherwise just feels strange to have to explicitly call `__new__` and `__init__` to instantiate an object.

What is the proper way to accomplish this? I would also appreciate any explanation for the undesired behavior in attempts 1 and 2.

Comment: Don't inherit from `int`.

Comment: `__new__()` is a class method, not an instance method - there is no `self` being passed to it.  Think about it - if an instance had already been created before `__new__` was called, then what possible use could it be to override that method?

Comment: @jasonharper I understand that much. The confusion is in why it would overwrite the attributes of other instances

Comment: You were setting attributes on the class itself.  All instances could see them.

Comment: For that matter, inheriting from `list` probably isn't the best approach either.

Comment: @jasonharper Ok, that makes sense. I didn't know that's how it would work

Comment: @asheets Don't subclass list or int.  You want to make objects that have a list, and have an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your `sequence` isn’t much of a type so far: calling `append` on it won’t preserve its indexed nature (let alone `sort` or slice assignment!).  If you just want to make lists that look like this, just write a **function** that returns a `list`.  Note that `list` itself behaves like such a function (it *was* one back in the Python 1 days!), so you can often still use it like a type.

So let’s talk just about `d0`.  Leaving aside the question of whether deriving from `int` is a good idea (it’s at least less work than deriving from `list` properly!), you have the basic idea correct: you *need* `__new__` for an immutable (base) type, because at `__init__` time it’s too late to choose its value.  So do so:

```
class d0(int):
  def __new__(cls,val,i,parent):
    return super().__new__(cls,val)
```

Note that this is a *class* method: there’s no instance yet, but we do need to know what class we’re instantiating (what if someone inherits from `d0`?).  This is what attempt **#1** got wrong: it thought the first argument was an instance to which to assign attributes.

Note also that we pass only one (other) argument up: `int` can’t use our ancillary data.  (Nor can it ignore it: consider `int('f',16)`.)  Thus failed **#2**: it sent all the arguments up.

We *can* install our other attributes now, but the right thing to do is use `__init__` to separate *manufacturing* an object from *initializing* it:

```
# d0 continued
  def __init__(self,val,i,parent):
    # super().__init__(val)
    self.i=i; self.parent=parent
```

Note that all the arguments appear again, even `val` which we ignore.  This is because calling a class involves only one argument list (*cf.* `d0(elem,i,self)`), so `__new__` and `__init__` have to share it.  (It would therefore be formally correct to pass `val` to `int.__init__`, but what would it do with it?  There’s no use in calling it at all since we know `int` is already completely set up.)  Using **#3** was painful because it didn’t follow this rule.